# If then inside while loop inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures, while-loop

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that contains a while loop that contains an if else statement but MySQL Workbench doesn't seem to know which END goes with which.  The outline is as such:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure()
BEGIN
    WHILE blah blah DO
        # do stuff
        If blah blah THEN
            # do more stuff
        ELSE IF blah blah THEN
            # do something else
        ELSE
            # try this
        END IF;
        # do even more stuff
    END WHILE;
END
|
```

It highlights the END of the END IF in red thinking it matched the BEGIN, and it highlights the END of the END WHILE saying "end without if".  How can I do this?

Comment: When someone is trying to write his first stored procedure and that includes a loop, almost invariably it is a JOIN that they are really looking for. This may not be correct in your case but ....

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the `WHILE`, change `ELSE IF ... THEN` to `ELSEIF ... THEN`. See [14.6.5.2 IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html).

Comment: Oopsie!  That did it- thank you!